# TYPO3 7.6 - Add a public function to the controller

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

I just try to create my first extension about flowers with a list view and and a detail view. Now I want to add the possibility to browse through the flowers on detail view.

I found the following code [Extbase Repository: findNext und findPrevious Funktionen](http://blog.teamgeist-medien.de/2014/10/extbase-repository-findnext-und-findprevious-funktionen.html)
and added it to my repository

```
 /**
 * The repository for Pflanzens
 */
class PflanzenRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository
{

    protected $defaultOrderings = array(
        'nameDeutsch' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
    );
    /**
     * Find next item by uid
     * @param integer $uid The uid of the current record
     * @return boolean|\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResult 
     */
    public function findNext($uid) {
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $result = $query->matching($query->greaterThan('uid',$uid))->setLimit(1)->execute();
        if($query->count()) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Find previous item by uid
     * @param integer $uid The uid of the current record
     * @return boolean|\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResult 
     */
    public function findPrev($uid) {
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $ordering = array('uid'=>\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING);
        $result = $query->matching($query->lessThan('uid',$uid))->setLimit(1)->setOrderings($ordering)->execute();
        if($query->count()) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
 }
```

This is my controller right now:

```
 /**
  * PflanzenController
  */
class PflanzenController extends    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{

    /**
     * pflanzenRepository
     *
     * @var \TMRuebe\Faerbepflanzen\Domain\Repository\PflanzenRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $pflanzenRepository = NULL;

    /**
     * action list
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function listAction()
    {
        $pflanzens = $this->pflanzenRepository->findAll();
            $this->view->assign('pflanzens', $pflanzens);
    }

    /**
     * action show
     *
     * @param \TMRuebe\Faerbepflanzen\Domain\Model\Pflanzen $pflanzen
     * @return void
     */
    public function showAction(\TMRuebe\Faerbepflanzen\Domain\Model\Pflanzen $pflanzen)
    {
        $this->view->assign('pflanzen', $pflanzen);
    }
}
```

Now I need help how to add the two public functions to the controller. And I also need a hint for the variable that I can use in my fluid template to create the previous link and the next link.

Answer (score 0):

in `showAction()` you need to assign to further variables with the results of `findNext()` and `findPrev()`.

```
$this->view->assign('previous', \TMRuebe\Faerbepflanzen\Domain\Repository\PflanzenRepository::findPrev($pflanzen['uid']));
$this->view->assign('next', \TMRuebe\Faerbepflanzen\Domain\Repository\PflanzenRepository::findNext($pflanzen['uid']));
```

in your detail template you need to build the links like the links in the list view.

You might build methods using the current object to get easier access to next and prev.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I get the following error: Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' |

Comment: I missed closing brackets. There are possibly more errors. this is an example so you can get the idea how to work.

Comment: Thanks again. Right now I get the error: 'Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Cannot use object of type TMRuebe\Faerbepflanzen\Domain\Model\Pflanzen as array '. I try to understand what I have to do but it's not that easy for me. I'm still looking for a good tutorial or book.